# HTML CSS JQUERY, Owl Carousel vue Jquery conflict

Tags: html, jquery, css

On the front-end side, I see OwlCarousel and Jquery conflicting. I bought datepicker via jquery, I used owl carousel basic, but when I delete the head part of jquery, owl carousel works, if I don't delete it, it doesn't work.

I changed the order, but this time the overlapping order changed. I tried deleting files such as jquery min.js (etc).

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 4,
    showButtonPanel: true
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <!-- local storage -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
  <!-- local storage end -->
  <!-- bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- bootstrap end -->
  <!-- jquery ui -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <!-- jquery ui end -->
  <!-- owl-carousel -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/owl.carousel@2.3.4/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/owl.carousel@2.3.4/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/owl.carousel@2.3.4/dist/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <!-- owl carosusel end -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  <title>Villa Papatya | Anasayfa</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Please add enough code to provide a [mre] and re-create the issue

Comment: Why are you putting jQuery in twice? first `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>` then second one in `<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>`  Think of it as calling multiple taxi when you want a ride...no need for multiple

Comment: I didn't know much about jquery, it was because I called it twice. Thank you.